# Flex cut off border when screen scroll

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, border

Hi I have following HTML code (here is "working" [example](https://jsfiddle.net/98orxaue/))

```html
<div class="layout">
    <main class="main">
       <nav class="menu">
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
      </nav>

      <section class="main__content">
        Some Content
      </section>

    </main>
</div>
```

And style:

```css
.layout {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    border-right: solid 3px red;
    width: 258px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.menu__item {
    height: 340px;
    width: 240px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #aaaaaa;
}
```

The problem is that on Chrome, when screen height is smaller than left menu and scrollbar appear, then menu right border (red) will be not rendered when scrollbar is move down. Desired behaviour is to draw red border to the end of vertical menu (so if we move scrollbar we should always see red border). How to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behavior when it comes to block elements. They become as high or wide as their parent, inline elements on the other hand, they grow with content.

There is several solutions to make the *red border* size with content, and here are 3, where I used the 2 mentioned in your own answer, to explain why they work:

1. Move it to the `main` children. This work because flex items behave like inline block, and grows with their content.
2. Make the outer most have a non fixed height, in this case the `layout`, by using `min-height` instead. This work as the flex container is now allowed to be higher than full viewport.
3. The `main` isn't allowed to grow but allowed to shrink due to the flex item default value is `flex: 0 1 auto`, so by setting it to `flex: 1 0 auto` those terms is swapped.

Stack snippet 1

```css
.layout {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    width: 258px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.menu  > div {
    border-right: solid 3px red;
}

.menu__item {
    height: 340px;
    width: 240px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
    <main class="main">
       <nav class="menu">
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
      </nav>

      <section class="main__content">
        Some Content
      </section>

    </main>
</div>
```

Stack snippet 2

```css
.layout {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    width: 258px;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-right: solid 3px red;
}

.menu__item {
    height: 340px;
    width: 240px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
    <main class="main">
       <nav class="menu">
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
      </nav>

      <section class="main__content">
        Some Content
      </section>

    </main>
</div>
```

Stack snippet 3

```css
.layout {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: flex;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    width: 258px;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-right: solid 3px red;
}

.menu__item {
    height: 340px;
    width: 240px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
    <main class="main">
       <nav class="menu">
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
            <div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>
      </nav>

      <section class="main__content">
        Some Content
      </section>

    </main>
</div>
```

---

When it comes to why the extra `div` wrapped around the `menu__item` work, is because a flex item by default always try to *shrink-to-fit* as it defaults to `flex: 0 1 auto`, but at the same time won't be smaller than its content, and as it is the extra `div` that is the *flex item*, with a sized content, it can.

When you use i.e. option 3 above, it will start to work without that `div` wrapper, as now the `main` is allowed to grow with its content, which will let the `menu__item` to keep its height.

Stack snippet

```css
.layout {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: flex;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    width: 258px;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-right: solid 3px red;
}

.menu__item {
    height: 340px;
    width: 240px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
    <main class="main">
       <nav class="menu">
            <div class="menu__item">Item</div>
            <div class="menu__item">Item</div>
            <div class="menu__item">Item</div>
            <div class="menu__item">Item</div>
      </nav>

      <section class="main__content">
        Some Content
      </section>

    </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why chrome behave in this way, but we can at least two solutions:

1. Change `height: 100vh;` in `.layout` class to `min-height: 100vh;`
2. Add `flex: 1 0 auto;` to `.main` class

May be someone can explain why chrome behave like this and why above solutions works?

I alsow wonder why if I change
`<div><div class="menu__item">Item</div></div>`
to `<div class="menu__item">Item</div>` all items will be squeezed to screen size ? (and in this case scrollbar (and problem) will disappear  but not in acceptable way)